# TikZ: can't add a break line into an equation in my flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a flowchart. Is it somehow possible to add a line break while working with equations? I have found a few solutions if there is no equation involved.

```
\node [block, below of=init] (calculation) {$V_{gas}=V_{reactor}-
V_{liquidphase} V_{calc}=V_{O2}+V_{N2}+V_{H2O}$};
```

I want each of these equations to be in a single line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You made no mistakes, but please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting an `array`, an `aligned` environment or something like that seems to work well enough:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {$\begin{aligned}
      V_{\text{gas}}&=V_{\text{reactor}}-V_{\text{liquidphase}} V_{\text{calc}}\\ 
      &=V_{\text{O}_2}+V_{\text{N}_2}+V_{\text{H}_2\text{O}}
  \end{aligned}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mix this with normal text blocks or alike, you may use the standard line break approach of Ti*k*Z by adding `align=left/center/right` to your nodes style. I chose left here and moved the second row to the right by a phantom.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, align=left] (calculation) {$V_\text{gas}=V_\text{reactor}-V_\text{liquidphase} V_\text{calc}$\\$\phantom{V_\text{gas}} =V_{\ce{O2}}+V_{\ce{N2}}+V_{\ce{H2O}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]